# Extensão do Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extensão

Estou com um problema, minha extensão não funciona de jeito algum, antes de tudo, irei explicar para que ela serve:

Essa extensão quando ativa faz a inserção de dados em um form de um determinado site da web, recebendo esses dados através de socket de um aplicativo feito em java.

No Google Chrome funciona perfeitamente, com um delay de 2 segundo para cada item adicionado ao form (Isso começou a acontecer recentemente, não sei o porquê), então com todos os testes que já fiz, isso se deve ao fato de alguma atualização de sua versão.

Mas mudando da água pro vinho, não vim pelo chrome e sim pelo mozilla, vou disponibilizar a extensão e fico no aguardo de ajuda.

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "name": "SGIR - Extensão",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Preencher formulários",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "//Determinado site da web"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["funcao.js"],
        "matches": ["//Determinado site da web"]
    }]
}
```

**Funcao:**

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:30000");
var itens = [];

ws.onopen = function ()
{
    ws.send("");
   // alert("Mensagem enviada...");
};

ws.onmessage = function (evt)
{
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    itens.push(received_msg);

    var ni = document.getElementById("NI");
    ni.value = itens[0].toString();

    var codigoacesso = document.getElementById("CodigoAcesso");
    codigoacesso.value = itens[1].toString();

    var senha = document.getElementById("Senha");
    senha.value = itens[2].toString();

    itens.splice(0,itens.length);
};

ws.onclose = function ()
{
    // websocket is closed.
    //alert("Conexão fechada...");
};

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    socket.close();
};
```

**Scriptjs:**

```
/* global browser */

browser.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    windowType: "normal",
    currentWindow: true
}, function (tab) {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab[0].id, {
        "file": "funcao.js"
    });
});
```

**Popup:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scriptjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        Programa criado por @netoschneider

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quais são os sintomas?

Comment: A extensão não funciona de jeito algum no mozilla, e no google chrome, estou tendo um delay de 3, 2 segundos para que a informação apareça no form @PabloAlmeida

Comment: Ok, mas não funciona por quê? Qual é o erro?

Comment: Então, isso é exatamente o que eu quero descobrir. Eu não vejo problemas no código, no chrome ele funciona, mas gera delay e isso surgiu do nada, eu não fiz alteração alguma no código, e no mozilla eu não sei o porque da extensão não funcionar.

Comment: Você já olhou o console do navegador?

Comment: Poderia me guiar? Como faço o debbug no mozilla pra poder ver o erro da extensão?

Comment: Aperte F12 pra abrir o console. Lá vai aparecer os erros e também tem uma aba com um depurador caso queira acompanhar a execução passo-a-passo.

Comment: No google chrome ele gera uma excessão: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at WebSocket.ws.onmessage ", mas nada que comprometa a execução no form, com delay como eu havia dito, e no mozilla não gera nada, ele simplesmente não funciona. @PabloAlmeida

Comment: No mozilla a extensão funciona, o que não funciona é a conexão websocket, simplesmente não conecta com o servidor, através do chrome a mesma extensão conecta, mas com o mozilla não.